# Transform a sfc_LINESTRING geometry to sfc_MULTIPOLYGON

Tags: r, r-sf

How could I transform a sfc_LINESTRING geometry into sfc_MULTIPOLYGON? The purpose is to have a dataframe with a number of records equal to the territorial units that I need to graphically represent associating data to them. The aggregation element would be a provincial code that I can extract from one of the columns ($ NATIONALCO) of the dataframe.

The original shapefile file comes from the Download Center of the National Geographic Institute (https://centrodedescargas.cnig.es), Reference geographic information, Municipal, provincial and autonomous limits.

```
> str(geoprovincias)
Classes ‘sf’ and 'data.frame':  5312 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ INSPIREID      : chr  "ES.IGN.BDDAE.M34121500000M97999900000T0225826" "ES.IGN.BDDAE.M34121500000M97999900000T0225560" "ES.IGN.BDDAE.M34121500000M97999900000T0225833" "ES.IGN.BDDAE.M34121500000M97999900000T0226291" ...
 $ NATIONALCO     : chr  "M34121500000M97999900000T0225826" "M34121500000M97999900000T0225560" "M34121500000M97999900000T0225833" "M34121500000M97999900000T0226291" ...
 $ COUNTRY        : chr  "ES" "ES" "ES" "ES" ...
 $ NATLEV         : chr  "https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/codelist/AdministrativeHierarchyLevel/3rdOrder" "https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/codelist/AdministrativeHierarchyLevel/3rdOrder" "https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/codelist/AdministrativeHierarchyLevel/3rdOrder" "https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/codelist/AdministrativeHierarchyLevel/3rdOrder" ...
 $ NATLEVNAME     : chr  "Provincia" "Provincia" "Provincia" "Provincia" ...
 $ LEGSTATUS      : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ACCURACY       : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ NAME_BOUND     : chr  "A Coruña#Océano Atlántico" "A Coruña#Océano Atlántico" "A Coruña#Océano Atlántico" "A Coruña#Océano Atlántico" ...
 $ DATE_BOUND     : Date, format: "2009-07-06" "2009-07-06" ...
 $ URL_RESOUR     : chr  "https://www.idee.es/csw-inspire-idee/srv/spa/catalog.search#/home" "https://www.idee.es/csw-inspire-idee/srv/spa/catalog.search#/home" "https://www.idee.es/csw-inspire-idee/srv/spa/catalog.search#/home" "https://www.idee.es/csw-inspire-idee/srv/spa/catalog.search#/home" ...
 $ geometry       :sfc_LINESTRING of length 5312; first list element:  'XY' num [1:13, 1:2] -9.28 -9.28 -9.28 -9.28 -9.28 ...
 $ CódigoProvincia: chr  "15" "15" "15" "15" ...
 - attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geometry"
 - attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:11] "INSPIREID" "NATIONALCO" "COUNTRY" "NATLEV" ...
>
```

**UPDATE**

`geoprovinces` generation r code.

```
geopropenínsula <- st_read("ruta/ll_provinciales_inspire_peninbal_etrs89.shp")

geoprocanarias <- st_read("ruta/ll_provinciales_inspire_canarias_wgs84.shp")

crs <- st_crs(geopropenínsula)

geoprocanariasco <- 
    geoprocanarias %>% 
    st_transform(crs) %>%
    st_geometry()
geoprocanariasco <- geoprocanariasco + c(5, 7)

geoprocanarias <- 
    geoprocanarias %>% 
    st_set_geometry(geoprocanariasco) %>%  
    st_set_crs(crs)

geoprovincias <- rbind(geopropenínsula, geoprocanarias)
geoprovincias$CódigoProvincia <- substring(geoprovincias$NATIONALCO, 6, 7)

geoprovincias %>%
 ggplot() +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_void()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `st_cast` to change to a multipolygon. I only used one of the shapefiles for the example below. You need to first cast it as a multilinestring, then you can convert that to a multipolygon.

```
library(sf)

geo <- st_read("ll_autonomicas_inspire_canarias_wgs84.shp")

mls <- st_cast(geo, "MULTILINESTRING") %>%
  st_cast(., "MULTIPOLYGON")
```

Output

```
mls

Simple feature collection with 1070 features and 10 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -18.16118 ymin: 27.63772 xmax: -13.33496 ymax: 29.41645
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84

library(mapview)
mapview::mapview(mls)
```

[image]

Comment: And to group by territorial unit, according to the variable ```CódigoProvincia```?. A sfc_MULTIPOLYGON for each different value of ```CódigoProvincia```

Comment: Can you provide the code you used to create geoprovincias?

Comment: I have updated the question with the ```geoprovincias``` generation r code

Comment: I have been checking these official files and have encountered various problems. There are two provinces (26 and 28, La Rioja and Madrid) that cannot be identified. And a "54" that does not correspond to any official province. Solving this problem is beyond my knowledge.

Comment: ```geoprovincias <- geoprovincias %>%
  group_by(CódigoProvincia) %>% 
  summarize(geometry = st_union(geometry))
```
I have used this code to perform grouping, but the issues described in the comment above prevent me from using this official geospatial data source. I apologize for the time you have spent.

Comment: @JoséCarlos I had an issue where there is not a complete polygon somewhere, but not sure where. You might take a look here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76729/cant-plot-polygons-with-r-invalid-number-of-points-in-linearring-found-3-mus